# How to fire notification in delphi XE10 seattle without vibration

Tags: android, delphi, notifications, delphi-10-seattle

In Android app, code fires silent notification when app goes in background. In Delphi XE8 it works fine - no sound, no vibration, but it behaves differently in Delphi XE10 - no sound, but there is vibration [vibration is off in user permissions]. How I can remove vibration?

```
begin
 MyNotification := NotificationCtr.CreateNotification;
try
 MyNotification.Name := ' Name';
 MyNotification.AlertBody := 'AlertBody';
 MyNotification.Number := 0;
 MyNotification.EnableSound := false;
 MyNotification.FireDate := Now;
 NotificationCtr.ScheduleNotification(MyNotification);
finally
 MyNotification.DisposeOf;
end; 
end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is reported as bug [RSP-12396](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-12396). It was fixed in Seattle 10 Update 1 released this week.